# Notifications take focus from other application (With ShowWithoutActivation)

Tags: vb.net, notifications

I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong here. I think I know where the problem is but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I use `ShowWithoutActivation()` to create a notification like form. It works fine until I use `Hide()` on it.

On the form:

```
  Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property ShowWithoutActivation() As Boolean
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property

Private Sub Message_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Message.Click
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
```

In my main form in a timer:

```
Dim newLocation As Point
            Dim ChosenScreen As Screen
            For Each screen As Screen In MonitorsList
                If (screen.DeviceName = List_Monitors.Text) Then
                    ChosenScreen = screen
                End If
            Next
            newLocation.X = (ChosenScreen.Bounds.Width / 2) - (NotifCallTimer.Width / 2)
            newLocation.Y = 30

            NotifCallTimer.Location = newLocation
            NotifCallTimer.Message.Text = "Something"

            NotifCallTimer.timerOnNotif.ForeColor = Color.White
            TimerFrontTAQT.ForeColor = Color.White
            NotifCallTimer.Show()
```

So it does this same code in a Select Case, and execute it after specific number of seconds. It work on the first time and not the one after that. After the first time, it take focus so if I was typing something in another software, focus goes to the notification instead.

The only difference is that I use `Hide()` on the Notification form in the meantime so that must be it. No idea what happen in `Hide()` for this to happen.

Any help appreciated.

regards,

Comment: @Ssein Thank you for the formating. Just hope someone could shed light on this issue...

Comment: Change the title of your question maybe you get your answer!! Or ask it in the Code Review forum